# Where can I find Protovis helper functions?

Tags: javascript, charts, protovis

Does anyone know where to find basic helper functions for using Protovis?  I'm thinking functions for plotting functions, xy points, boxplots, and the like.  I don't need a ton of customization, just the basic functionality of graphing these types of graphs.

It'd be a nice time-saver if helper functions existed, otherwise I'll have to look at the examples and make my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it will satisfy your needs, but you can always check out CCC, a "Charting library on top of protovis".

It supports dot graphs, line graphs, bar (box?) charts, area graphs, and more.

I've worked quite some time with protovis itself and CCC seems like a good option, perhaps I would have gone with it myself if I hadn't already created my own utility functions.

See the playgroud here: http://www.webdetails.pt/ccc/pvcTest.html

... and the sourcecode on Git: https://github.com/pmalves/ccc

Answer (score 0):

See if you find any of these function helpful:

> https://github.com/mbostock/protovis/tree/master/examples
>
> https://github.com/eagereyes/Protovis-Primer